# Display and Manipulate state values in a customised manner

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state

I have a form in react which has multiple form fields. The user inputs the values in the form fields and it is stored in the state of the component. Now I want to display the state of the component in a particular way.

So right now my state looks like this:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "typeA": [
        {
          "name": "abc"
        },
        {
          "number": "13,14"
        }
      ],
      "typeB": [
        {
          "country": "xyz"
        },
        {
          "date": "2019-05-14"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I want an output like this:

```
groups: {
"typeA": [[abc],[13,14]],
"typeB": [[2019-05-14],[xyz]]
}
```

I want to know how to manipulate the values stored in the state to look like my desired output. 
I am a beginner in react and dont know how to manipulate the state values. Please can anybody help me out with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use reduce on groups.

```
var state = {
  "groups": [
    {
      "typeA": [
        {
          "name": "abc"
        },
        {
          "number": "13,14"
        }
      ],
      "typeB": [
        {
          "country": "xyz"
        },
        {
          "date": "2019-05-14"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

var output = state.groups //iterating over groups using reduce
.reduce((final, s)=> { // final:-output object , s:- group array element
  const values = Object.keys(s) // iterating over key element keys e.g. "typeA"
      .reduce((out, o)=> {  // out: value of key, o: element of keyArray e.g state.groups.typeA
        out[o] = s[o].map(k => Object.values(k)) //returning values in array
        return out;
        }, {})
  final =  {...final, ...values} // update the output
  return final;
}, {})

console.log(output) // "{"typeA":[["abc"],["13,14"]],"typeB":[["xyz"],["2019-05-14"]]}"
```

Comment: could you please explain this function, as it is not printing anything. So, im not sure how this works

Comment: @user8306074 i have updated the answer with explanation. If still have doubts you can console the values

Comment: Hi @Harish, I understand the code now, but when I'm executing it, it shows "TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined" error. I have written it inside a function and the argument of the function is the json format of the state

Comment: Let me know how are you using it? what is your initial state? if its not an array it will not work. `reduce` will work only on array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56141404/typeerror-cannot-read-property-reduce-of-undefined-in-react