# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined in react

Tags: json, reactjs, state, reduce

I have a form in which I am asking the user to input field values for a couple of fields, storing the field values in an state and displaying the state values in a customised format.

So, I have a couple of input fields and a submit button:

```
<button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
         {
           this.state.credentials &&
           //<Credentials value={this.state}/>
            <Credentials value={JSON.stringify(this.state, undefined, 2)} />
         }
```

The Credentials function convert the state of the component in JSON format:

```
const Credentials = ({value} ) => {
    return <pre>{formatState(value)}</pre>;
}
```

The formatState function will basically manipulate the state values and display them in the way I want:

```
function formatState(state) {
  console.log("hi")
  console.log(state);
    const output = state.groups.reduce((final, s)=> {
      console.log(output)
      const values = Object.keys(s).reduce((out, o)=> {
        out[o] = s[o].map(k => Object.values(k))
        return out;
        }, {})
        final =  {...final, ...values}
        return final;
      }, {})
      console.log(output) 
  }
```

The state looks like this:

```
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "typeA": [
        {
          "name": "abc"
        },
        {
          "number": "13,14"
        }
      ],
      "typeB": [
        {
          "country": "xyz"
        },
        {
          "date1": "2019-05-14"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want the output like this:

```
groups: {
"typeA": [[abc],[13,14]],
"typeB": [[2019-05-14],[xyz]]
}
```

SO, reduce function is used to convert the state into the following output. But I getting the error : 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined"

Please can anybody tell me why this is happening.

Comment: Don't `stringify` the `state`, while passing value to `Credentials`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is here `<Credentials value={JSON.stringify(this.state, undefined, 2)} />`. [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) produces string representaion of some object (`this.state` in your case). Argument `state` of `formatState` has type of string. It seems that you want to have `state` arguemnt to be object. So you should do

```
<Credentials value={this.state} />
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Could you also tell me how to display the "final" on the screen? because I can see my output on the console but not on the screen

Comment: Your `formatState(state)` doen't return value. add `return output` to the end of `formatState(state)`

Comment: I added a return output statement after console.log() in formatState(state). But it gives me this error: "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {typeA, typeB}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

Comment: Here `JSON.Stringify` may help. Do `return JSON.Stringify(output)`

Comment: Please consider accepting answer if it looks ok to you.